# Confusing in rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I couldn't figure out why this happens after stumbling around Michael Hartl tutorial.

When I click the submit form and expect fail, the expected url after rendering should be '/signup' but some reasons it is '/users'

This is my controller

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
  end
```

This is my routes

```
resources :users
match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
```

First of all when I click the signup link the url is

```
http://localhost:3000/signup
```

Then submisson fails this url is

```
http://localhost:3000/users
```

Could anyone explain me why it happens ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are posting to the UsersController (to create a new user, from your signup action), you're invoking the `#create` action. If you view source on that page, you'll see that the form action is `/users` and the form method is `POST`. So when you submit the form, the request made is:

```
POST /users
(some data)
```

If the save fails, then your create action there just renders the "new" template. You don't get redirected anywhere. `render :action => "new"` just renders the template for the `new` action - it doesn't actually redirect to the new action, or run its action code.

Answer (score 0):

According to routes.rb usage in rails, `match` tag in your routes.rb file determines which `controller/action` to reach if there is a match.

So here, your signup url is matching to `user` controller-> `new` action. But if the `new` action fails, the url is **NOT /signup** but `user` controller's `new` function instead. So the url displays like that. Hope I made it somewhat clearer.